# How to clear checkboxes when reset button is clicked

Tags: android, checkbox

In my project I have a number of checkboxes in a linear layout. When running the project by default all checkboxes are unchecked and I need to check some checkboxes. Below the checkboxes there is a reset button. When the reset button is clicked all the checkboxes are unchecked. How do I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 12):

Call this in onClick()of Reset button.

```
if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
             checkBox1.setChecked(false);
         }
if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
             checkBox2.setChecked(false);
         }
```

.
.
.
and so on

Answer (score 5):

To Uncheck all checked CheackBoxes keep references of the checked Checkboxes in ListView/Array and when reset button is clicked mark them as unchecked,

```
ListView <CheckBox> selectedcheckBox = new ListView<CheckBox> ();
```

when Checkbox is Checked---

```
selectedcheckBox.add(referanceofckeckbox).
```

now when reset button is clicked

```
public void onclick(View v){

 for(CheckBox cb : selectedcheckBox){
 cb.setChecked(false);

} 

}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            checkBox.toggle();
        }
use this for all the checkboxes used.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old stuff, but has no valid answer so maybe this one helps anyone.

jQuery + CSS selectors work very well for this. If you just want to uncheck all those checkboxes that are checked you just need the following code:

```
$('[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

While if you want to toggle all you can add variable to hold the checked status like this:

```
var isChecked = $('[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
$('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !isChecked);
```